# WARNING: No mapping found

Tags: spring, web.xml

I am trying to build a simple sp[ring mvc in which there is only a single jsp login page.But i am not been able to view it on running the application as i am getting following warnings in console :

WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringBlogger/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringBlogger'

web.xml :

view plaincopy to clipboardprint?
Note: Text content in the code blocks is automatically word-wrapped

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
  <display-name>SpringBlogger</display-name>  
  <welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>login.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  

  <servlet>  
<servlet-name>SpringBlogger</servlet-name>  
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>  
<servlet-name>SpringBlogger</servlet-name>  
<url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

SpringBlogger-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>  

<mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beans" />  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
   </bean>  
</beans>
```

HomeController.java:-

```
    package com.beans;  

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  

@Controller  
public class HomeController {  

    @RequestMapping("/login.jsp")  
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap map){  
        map.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Spring Blogger");  
        return "login";  
    }  
}
```

login.jsp :-

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Insert title here</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="LoginAction" method="post">  
<h1>${message}</h1>  
<table>  
<tr>  
<td>UserName: </td>  
<td><form:input path="UserName"/>  
</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Password: </td>  
    <td><form:password path="Password"/></td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td colspan="2">  
        <input type="submit" value="submit">  
    </td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

i know this type of issues already mentioned in some other threads but i am not getting my problem resolved as i already include  but still getting the same error.

Please let me know what i am missing.

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `*.jsp` as servlet mapping in your `web.xml`. Use simple slash `/`.

Comment: What version of Spring are your using and what servlet container?

Comment: spring 3.1 and apache tomcat 7

Answer (score 0):

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"  version="3.0">  
  <display-name>SpringBlogger</display-name>  
      <welcome-file-list>  
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>  

<servlet>  
    <servlet-name>SpringBlogger</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
</servlet>  

<servlet-mapping>  
       <servlet-name>SpringBlogger</servlet-name>  
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
</servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

SpringBlogger-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context   
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">  
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>  

<mvc:annotation-driven/>  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.beans.*" />  

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />  
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
   </bean>  
</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.beans;  

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;  
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;  

@Controller  
public class HomeController {  

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method=RequestMethod.POST")  
    public String showHomePage(ModelMap map){  
        map.addAttribute("message", "Welcome to Spring Blogger");  
        return "login";  
    }  
}
```

login.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">  
<title>Insert title here</title>  
</head>  
<body>  
<form action="/login" method="post">  
<h1>${message}</h1>  
<table>  
<tr>  
<td>UserName: </td>  
<td><form:input path="UserName"/>  
</td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td>Password: </td>  
    <td><form:password path="Password"/></td>  
</tr>  

<tr>  
    <td colspan="2">  
        <input type="submit" value="submit">  
    </td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: index.jsp file shoulb be your welcome file from there you are calling HomeController and HomeController will return you login.jsp file which is inside WEB-INF/jsp folder